# Not using prependTo but completely refreshing div

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to completely rewrite the content in a div rather than using prependTo and adding to the most recent? What jQuery function should I use?

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "london.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function( xmlResponse ) {
        var data = $( "geoname", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
          return {
            value: $( "name", this ).text() + ", " +
              ( $.trim( $( "countryName", this ).text() ) || "(unknown country)" ),
            id: $( "geonameId", this ).text()
          };
        }).get();
        $( "#match" ).autocomplete({
          source: data,
          minLength: 0,
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
              "Selected: " + ui.item.value + ", geonameId: " + ui.item.id :
              "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

<div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to rewrite the inner HTML of a DOM element. I would rewrite your function:

```
function log( message ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( $( "<div/>" ).text( message ) ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
}
```

Or use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) if you want it to strip HTML, so your function would rewrite to:

```
function log( message ) {
  $( "#log" ).text(message);
}
```

Comment: Does `.html()` allow you to pass in DOM elements? The documentation just says it takes an HTML string.

Comment: No, `.html()` only accepts a string. If you want to overwrite using DOM objects you'll want to use `$(elem).empty().append(dom_object_to_add, another_dom_object_to_add, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

for a completely rewrite you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
.html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Change

```
$( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
```

to

```
$("#log" ).html( "<div>"+message+"</div>" );
```